# Calculation in Classes with Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, class

I got a task to calculate the area for a rectangle within a class.
I need also `input()` for the width and height.

I have written a class and make it work, but can I do it cleaner or something else to improve the class?

```
class Rectangle:

    def __int__(self, width, height):
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height

   def Input(self):
       self.width = float(input("width: "))
       self.height = float(input("height: "))

   def Calculator(self):
      self.Area = (self.width*self.height)
      print("The area is " + str(self.Area))

rec = Rectangle()
rec.Input()
rec.Calculator()
```

Comment: The best way to improve this code would be to get rid of the class. What school teaches its students to use classes like this...?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I see, but it was some simple tasks just to get to know classes and objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this also you had issues in your code and I have fixed them.

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self._width = width
        self._height = height

    def calculator(self):
        area = self._width*self._height
        print('The area is {}'.format(area))

Rectangle(float(input()), float(input())).calculator()
```

NOTE: method names should be all in **lowercase**.

Comment: Why does the class's `__init__` convert its arguments to floats? That looks like bad design to me. What if someone wants to use ints?

Comment: It was in his method. He cast the input to float in Input method. And it was asked to make the class as clean as possible.

Comment: Yes, but in the OP's code the `float` conversion was coupled with the `input`. I could create a `Rectangle` with integers if I wanted to (if the constructor weren't broken, that is). In your code, that's not really possible.

Comment: How would you write it then? Thanks for all the answer also!  @Aran-Fey

Comment: As I said before, his aim was not passing an integer, therefore, I see no mistake of casting in the __init__.

Comment: @Rapoo The `float` is only there because the inputs are strings, so it should go around the `input`: `Rectangle(float(input()), float(input()))` or thereabouts.

Comment: You can either cast the inputs before giving them as a parameter or create 2 methods which cast to int and float and call them respectively.

Comment: @Rapoo if my answer is a solution for you, please accept it as the answer and upvote it so the question can be closed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I changed the answer but still see no point for the downvote. You can do anything in the programming if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I marked it as "answered". @Rarblack